# Is it possible to forward the current user's FormsAuthentication Identity to another Controller action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I'd like to use ASP.NET MVC's views as mail template engine. For that, I am calling one controller action from another controller action using a System.ComponentModel.Component.WebClient, parse the returned web page and send it via e-mail.

In this scenario, is it possible to forward the current user's login credentials (I am using FormsAuthentication) to the controller action requested by the WebClient? User passwords are encrypted, so I can't just create a new NetworkCredentials instance with his user name and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just copy the .ASPXAUTH cookie from your current `Request` object to the `WebClient`

EDIT: I haven't actually tried this myself, so maybe the .ASPXAUTH cookie is removed from the Request object for security reasons.

But since you have access to the machine key, you can create your own cookies on the fly. Here's the code that should do it (I can't find the project where I actually did that)

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(User.Identity.Name, true, 5);
string aspxAuthCookieValue = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

This code creates a forms authentication cookie for your current user name and with an expiration time of 5 minutes.

Comment: Sounds good and I figured out the webclient part of setting a cookie, but how can I read .ASPXAUTH? For some reason the following term is true, even though I am logged in: 

requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Value.Length==0

Comment: I've added a way around this in my answer

Comment: Just read your comment again: you should look in HttpContext.REQUEST not RESPONSE !

Comment: Yup you're right. Thanks for the hint and sorry for the mixup!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing a http request, aren't you looking for something like "[rendering a view to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)"

Comment: That's what I tried first too, but after much googling around and trying different approaches for doing this (none of which were working with ASP.NET MVC 1.0 final), I chose a webclient instead. Performance is not an issue here, so I don't really care about the overhead.